# Can I control what step names IntelliJ includes when offering to complete one?

Tags: intellij-idea, automation, cucumber, gherkin

I am using `Cucumber` with `Gherkin` syntax.

I would like to show only the relevant step names in the combo box.
I am aware of the "offline" work I need to do for this.

My question is if it's possible to select which step names will enter to the combo box? (rather then all step names)

see image:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: #off, which IDE you are using? @gran33

Comment: As the question tags says: 'IntelliJ'

Comment: yes, thanks for info! @gran33.

Comment: The short answer is that they don't support this, and probably won't for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) on scenarios or features or both, then the IDE should only show steps that are within the scope of the tag.